# print like this * "a" -> "a1" * "aabbbaa" -> "a2b3a2"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs, underscore.js

- I am new to js.
- can you tell me how to print like this  * "a"     -> "a1" * "aabbbaa" -> "a2b3a2"

  - i tried with hash map but test cases failing.
  - providing my code below.
  - i am not good in hash map.
  - can you tell me how to solve with hash map so that in future I can fix it my self.
  - not sure what data structure to use for this one.
  - providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
const _ = require("underscore");

const rle = ( input ) => {

  console.log("input--->" + input);

  //var someString ="aaa";
    var someString = input;

  var arr = someString.split("");
  var numberCount = {};
  for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    var alphabet = arr[i];

    if(numberCount[alphabet]){

        numberCount[alphabet] = numberCount[alphabet] + 1;

       }
    else{
        numberCount[alphabet] = 1;

       }
  }

  console.log("a:" + numberCount['a'], "b:" + numberCount['b']);


}

/**
 * boolean doTestsPass()
 * Returns true if all the tests pass. Otherwise returns false.
 */
/**
 * Returns true if all tests pass; otherwise, returns false.
 */
const doTestsPass = () => {

  const VALID_COMBOS = {"aaa": "a3", "aaabbc":"a3b2c1"};

  let testPassed = true;

  _.forEach(VALID_COMBOS, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key, rle(key));
  if (value !== rle(key)) {
    testPassed = false;
  }
  });

  return testPassed;
}


/**
 * Main execution entry.
 */
if(doTestsPass())
{
  console.log("All tests pass!");
}
else
{
  console.log("There are test failures.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

- match groups of characters,
- get the character and the count and
- join it to a string.

```js
function runLengthEncoding(string) {
    return string
        .match(/(.)\1*/g)           // keep same characters in a single string
        .map(s => s[0] + s.length)  // take first character of string and length
        .join('');                  // create string of array
}

console.log(['a', 'aaa', 'aaabbc'].map(runLengthEncoding));
```

This is a bit more understandable version which iterates the given string and count the characters. If a different character is found, the last character and count is added to the result string.

At the end, a check is made, to prevent counting of empty strings and the last character cound is added to the result.

```js
function runLengthEncoding(string) {
    var result = '',
        i,
        count = 0,
        character = string[0];

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (character === string[i]) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        result += character + count;
        character = string[i];
        count = 1;
    }
    if (count) {
        result += character + count;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(['', 'a', 'aaa', 'aaabbc'].map(runLengthEncoding));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` the array into a multidimensional array. `map` and `join` the array to convert to string.

```js
const rle = (input) => {
  return input.split("").reduce((c, v) => {
    if (c[c.length - 1] && c[c.length - 1][0] === v) c[c.length - 1][1]++;
    else c.push([v, 1]);
    return c;
  }, []).map(o => o.join('')).join('');
}

console.log(rle("a"));
console.log(rle("aabbbaa"));
console.log(rle("aaaaaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `rle` doesn't return a result.

Also note, this implementation may pass the test cases you wrote, but not the examples you mentioned in your question: for the string "aabbaa" this will produce "a4b2", not " a2b2a2" .

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution:

```js
function runLengthEncoding(str) {
  let out = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    let temp = str[i];
    let count = 1;
    while (i < str.length && str[i+1] == temp) {
      ++count;
      ++i;
    }
    out += temp + count;
  } // end-for
  return out;
}

console.log(runLengthEncoding("a"));
console.log(runLengthEncoding("aabbbaa"));
console.log(runLengthEncoding("aaaaaa"));
```